# Confusion about what the WPF Dispatcher object is

Tags: wpf

Could someone tell me in simple layman terms, what a WPF Dispatcher object is?

Also, I sometimes see this line of code in the constructor of an object. What does Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher represent?

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
```

I know this has got something to do with making sure you don't access objects from a thread different from the thread that owns the object, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around exactly what a Dispatcher is/does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) should give a good description, in short:

> The **Dispatcher** maintains a prioritized queue of work items for a specific thread.

And the [`CurrentDispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher.aspx%5C):

> If a [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) is not associated with the current thread, a new [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) will be created. This is not the case with the [FromThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.fromthread.aspx) method. [FromThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.fromthread.aspx) will return **null** if there is not a dispatcher associated with the specified thread.

Answer (score 1):

http://weblogs.asp.net/pawanmishra/archive/2010/06/06/understanding-dispatcher-in-wpf.aspx

The main UI thread is the only thread that can access the user interface.
The dispatcher is a means of passing messages to the main UI thread.